# Get the column entries of an array with column size unknown

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a NumPy array `nd_arr`, which stores nx3 values with the columns n ranging from 0 to 10 (so it could also be empty).
Is there a reliable way to read the columns into three separate arrays?

I know I could do it with a for-loop and append every respective element to a new list, or predetermine the NumPy array size and insert the elements accordingly.
However, I am searching for a more universal solution.

I tried to use something like `vec_1 = nd_arr[:,0]` for all 3 columns, where this should give me the first column.
This works for n>=2.
But it gives me an index error (no second dimension for 1D vector recognizable) when n<2.

Is there something similar, that works for all n>=0 as well??

---

MWE:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])  
arr2 = np.array([1,2,3])  
arr3 = np.array([])  

# each line should return the individual columns as a,b and c
a,b,c = arr1[:,0], arr1[:,1], arr1[:,2]  
a,b,c = arr2[:,0], arr2[:,1], arr2[:,2] # this does not work  
a,b,c = arr3[:,0], arr3[:,1], arr3[:,2] # this does not work
```

---

Current Work Around:

```
if len(a:= arr.flatten()) >= 3:
    a,b,c = a[0::3], a[1::3], a[2::3]
else:
    a,b,c = [],[],[]
```

Comment: Please take a look on [how to create minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It is hard to understand your problem now, with example it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: Look at the `shapes`. (3,3), (3,), (0,).  Only the first is 2d.  You can use `arr2[0]` or even `arr2[...,0]`.

Comment: This is exactly the problem! I have three cases:  
    1. For columns >1:    a,b,c = arr1[:,0], arr1[:,1], arr1[:,2]  
    2. For columns =1:    a,b,c =   arr1[0],  arr1[1],   arr1[2]  
    3. For columns =0:    a,b,c = [ ],[ ],[ ]

Comment: How do you expect this to work?  `arr2` and `arr3` don't have rows and columns.  You can't use 2D indexing on a 1D array.  You could reshape `arr2` to (1,3), but you can't do anything with `arr3`.  Even `arr3[0]` will cause a fault.